# How to check if a device is running on Stock OS?

Tags: android

I know we can detect which version of OS the device is running on. I wish to know if the device is running on Android stock OS/Oxygen OS/MIUI/Funtouch OS. Basically I wish to detect if the device is running on a custom OS or not. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want to check this from within your app? If so, you could use Google's [SafetyNet Attestation API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation). On more recent devices with newer KeyMaster implementations it's also possible to use [key attestation data](https://source.android.com/security/keystore/attestation) to obtain info such as whether the device has a verified, locked bootloader.

Comment: Possible easier way: `System.getProperty( "os.version" )`

Comment: @greeble31 sorry but this does not give what is required.